# reStructuresText (rst) viewer with Sphinx

Tags: software-recommendation

So the title is already self-explanatory.
I am doing documentation with rst about my Python project. When using Pycharm I get errors so I tried using another viewer.

I tried [restview](https://mg.pov.lt/restview/) but had the same problem.

After some reasearch I found my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130720/sphinx-unknown-directive-type-toctree-error-in-pycharm-but-index-html-works). Apparently is because Sphinx is something apart. So I just need a viewer to render my rst files **LOCALLY**.

I founded [sphinx-view](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-view/0.1.4/) but I believe is not working for the moment as I get the error:

```
sphinx.errors.ApplicationError: Source directory and destination directory cannot be identical
```

Which I believe has to do with [this](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/5427)

Comment: Did you tried [ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/)? Have you read [getting started](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/getting-started-with-sphinx.html)?

Comment: I don't see any descriptions of why would ReText be any different. I believe it doesn't support Sphinx, I will have the same problems as with restview.
I have read the getting started of Spinx of course. I can generate the HTML but I was hoping for a live renderer actually.

Answer (score 4):

[Formiko](https://github.com/ondratu/formiko) - reStructuredText and MarkDown editor and live html previewer is available to install in Ubuntu.

It uses the Python docutils library as does Sphinx for generating html from reStructuredText, so compatibility should be good (I've not tested extensively).